# python tkinter You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

can someone help?

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\huzey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 506, in cmd_query
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\huzey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\huzey\OneDrive\Masaüstü\gui\loginsystem.py", line 198, in add_customer
    my_cursor.execute(sql_command, values)
  File "C:\Users\huzey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 269, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "C:\Users\huzey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 510, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near ')' at line 1
```

this is the full error and this is the part of the code that have error:

```
def add_customer():
    sql_command = "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, addres, phone, email, age, country, rent) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, )"
    values = (first_name_box.get(), last_name_box.get(), address_box.get(), phone_box.get(), email_box.get(), age_box.get(), country_box.get(), rent_box.get())
    my_cursor.execute(sql_command, values)
    mydb.commit()
    clear_all()
```

btw im tryng to make a real estate managment system. if you have any idea im open to new ideas and about the code i can give details if you want.

Comment: btw, there's a typo in your code: `addres` (should be `address`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end:

```
... VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, )
```

Get rid of that – and while you're at it, you can split the statement into multiple literals for more readability:

```
sql_command = (
    "INSERT INTO customers "
    "(first_name, last_name, addres, phone, email, age, country, rent) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
```

Comment: thank you the first error is gon but now i have another error like this: Unknown column 'addres' in 'field list' ... and the error is in this line: my_cursor.execute(sql_command, values)

Comment: Try `address` instead.